# Complete ObservableDictionary

Tags: c#, event-handling, wpf, hash-map, collections

In conjunction with a recent question of [mine](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/190810/object-pooling-in-wpf?noredirect=1#comment366194_190810), I found that an `ObservableDictionary` would be very handy for my situation, so I decided to implement one.

I've written a few custom observable collections and objects before, but this one was a bit different, in that `NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs` usually accepts an integer as it's modified index. Well, guess what `Dictionary` doesn't have any specific order in it and it also doesn't use integers as keys 100% of the time.

I started thinking of alternative collections and the first thing obviously that popped in my mind was a `List<KeyValuePair<,>>` but since initializing kvp's everytime takes way too much space and it looks awful (I even shortened it here!), I decided to make proper abstraction and add a small wrapper class, but shortly I found that there already is one `DictionaryEntry`. Combining that with a custom `KeyedCollection<>`, did the job fairly well.

So that's what I'm using behind the scenes, there is also a Dictionary, which only use is to get the `Keys` and `Values` properties separated more easily.

One odd thing about the `KeyedCollection<>` is it's indexer, since it doesn't have a setter, I had to save the index of the item currently modified, remove the item and insert a new copy at the same index. Which seems like too much work but I couldn't think of anything better.

I have tried to make it feel like a normal `Dictionary<,>` as much as possible, explicitly implementing some methods and properties, keeping the same constructors, etc. Tho I feel like I might've left some stuff implicitly implemented.

As for unit testing, I've been mostly comparing the content of the dictionary and the messages from the 2 fired events, to the native .NET's `ObservableCollection`, everything seems good and there are no errors, but if you find a discrepancy please let me know.

### KeyedEntryCollection<>

```
public class KeyedEntryCollection<TKey> : KeyedCollection<TKey, DictionaryEntry>
{
    public KeyedEntryCollection()
    {            
    }

    public KeyedEntryCollection(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer) 
        : base(comparer)
    {           
    }

    public int IndexOf(TKey key)
        => this.Contains(key) ? base.IndexOf(new DictionaryEntry(key, this[key].Value)) : -1;

    protected override TKey GetKeyForItem(DictionaryEntry entry) => (TKey)entry.Key;
}
```

### ObservableDictionary<,>

```
[Serializable]
public sealed class ObservableDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IDictionary<TKey, TValue>, IDictionary, ISerializable,
    IDeserializationCallback, INotifyCollectionChanged, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private const string IndexerName = "Item[]";
    private const string ValuesName = "Values";
    private const string KeysName = "Keys";

    public event NotifyCollectionChangedEventHandler CollectionChanged;

    private event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    event PropertyChangedEventHandler INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
    {
        add => PropertyChanged += value;
        remove => PropertyChanged -= value;
    }

    private readonly SerializationInfo _serializationInfo;

    private bool _requiresSyncronization;

    private KeyedEntryCollection<TKey> _keyedEntryCollection;

    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> _dictionary;

    private Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Dictionary
    {
        get
        {
            if (_requiresSyncronization)
            {
                _dictionary = _keyedEntryCollection.ToDictionary(entry => (TKey)entry.Key,
                    entry => (TValue)entry.Value);
                _requiresSyncronization = false;
            }
            return _dictionary;
        }
    }

    #region Constructors

    public ObservableDictionary(IDictionary<TKey, TValue> dictionary, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
        : this(comparer)
    {
        if (dictionary == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(dictionary));
        }
        foreach (var kvp in dictionary)
        {
            AddEntry(kvp);
        }
    }

    public ObservableDictionary(IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = null)
    {
        _keyedEntryCollection = new KeyedEntryCollection<TKey>(comparer);
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Used for deserialization.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="info"></param>
    /// <param name="context"></param>
    private ObservableDictionary(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        _serializationInfo = info;
    }

    #endregion

    #region KeyedEntryCollection Modifiers

    private void AddEntry(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> keyValuePair)
    {
        var entry = new DictionaryEntry(keyValuePair.Key, keyValuePair.Value);
        _keyedEntryCollection.Add(entry);
        _requiresSyncronization = true;

        OnCommonPropertiesChanged();
        OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Add, keyValuePair, _keyedEntryCollection.Count - 1);
    }

    private void AddEntry(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        AddEntry(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>(key, value));
    }

    private bool RemoveEntry(TKey key)
    {
        var itemIndex = _keyedEntryCollection.IndexOf(key);
        if (itemIndex != -1)
        {
            var value = _keyedEntryCollection[key];
            _keyedEntryCollection.RemoveAt(itemIndex);

            _requiresSyncronization = true;

            OnCommonPropertiesChanged();
            OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Remove, value, itemIndex);

        }
        return false;
    }

    private void SetEntry(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        if (_keyedEntryCollection.Contains(key))
        {
            var entry = _keyedEntryCollection[key];
            var entryIndex = _keyedEntryCollection.IndexOf(entry);
            if (!entry.Value.Equals(value))
            {
                _keyedEntryCollection.Remove(key);
                _keyedEntryCollection.Insert(entryIndex, new DictionaryEntry(key, value));
            }

            _requiresSyncronization = true;

            OnCommonPropertiesChanged();
            OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Replace, entry, new DictionaryEntry(key, value), entryIndex);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IEnumerable

    public void Clear()
    {
        _keyedEntryCollection.Clear();

        OnCommonPropertiesChanged();
        OnCollectionReset();
    }

    IDictionaryEnumerator IDictionary.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    void IDictionary.Remove(object key)
    {
        RemoveEntry((TKey)key);
    }

    object IDictionary.this[object key]
    {
        get => TryGetValue((TKey)key, out var value) ? (object)value : null;
        set => this[(TKey)key] = (TValue)value;
    }

    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>> IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>

    public void Add(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        AddEntry(item);
    }

    bool IDictionary.Contains(object key)
    {
        return _keyedEntryCollection.Contains((TKey)key);
    }

    void IDictionary.Add(object key, object value)
    {
        AddEntry(new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>((TKey)key, (TValue)value));
    }

    void ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Clear()
    {
        Clear();
    }

    public bool Contains(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return _keyedEntryCollection.Contains(new DictionaryEntry(item.Key, item.Value));
    }

    public void CopyTo(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>[] array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        if (array == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(array));
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < _keyedEntryCollection.Count; i++)
        {
            var entry = _keyedEntryCollection[i];
            array[i] = new KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>((TKey)entry.Key, (TValue)entry.Value);
        }
    }

    public bool Remove(KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue> item)
    {
        return RemoveEntry(item.Key);
    }

    void ICollection.CopyTo(Array array, int arrayIndex)
    {
        ((ICollection)_keyedEntryCollection).CopyTo(array, arrayIndex);
    }

    int ICollection.Count => _keyedEntryCollection.Count;
    object ICollection.SyncRoot => ((ICollection)_keyedEntryCollection).SyncRoot;
    bool ICollection.IsSynchronized => ((ICollection)_keyedEntryCollection).IsSynchronized;
    int ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.Count => _keyedEntryCollection.Count;
    ICollection IDictionary.Values => Dictionary.Values;
    bool IDictionary.IsReadOnly => false;
    public bool IsFixedSize => false;
    bool ICollection<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>.IsReadOnly => false;

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IDictionary<TKey,TValue>

    public Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
    {
        return Dictionary.GetEnumerator();
    }

    public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
    {
        return _keyedEntryCollection.Contains(key);
    }

    public void Add(TKey key, TValue value)
    {
        AddEntry(key, value);
    }

    public bool Remove(TKey key)
    {
        return RemoveEntry(key);
    }

    public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
    {
        if (_keyedEntryCollection.Contains(key))
        {
            value = (TValue)_keyedEntryCollection[key].Value;
            return true;
        }
        value = default(TValue);
        return false;
    }

    public TValue this[TKey key]
    {
        get => (TValue)_keyedEntryCollection[key].Value;
        set => SetEntry(key, value);
    }

    ICollection<TKey> IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Keys => Dictionary.Keys;
    ICollection IDictionary.Keys => Dictionary.Keys;
    ICollection<TValue> IDictionary<TKey, TValue>.Values => Dictionary.Values;

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of ISerializable

    [SecurityPermission(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Flags = SecurityPermissionFlag.SerializationFormatter)]
    void ISerializable.GetObjectData(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context)
    {
        var entries = new DictionaryEntry[_keyedEntryCollection.Count];
        for (int i = 0; i < entries.Length; i++)
        {
            entries[i] = _keyedEntryCollection[i];
        }
        info.AddValue("entries", entries);
        info.AddValue("comparer", _keyedEntryCollection.Comparer);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Implementation of IDeserializationCallback

    public void OnDeserialization(object sender)
    {
        var entries = (DictionaryEntry[])_serializationInfo.GetValue("entries", typeof(DictionaryEntry[]));
        var comparer =
            (EqualityComparer<TKey>)_serializationInfo.GetValue("comparer", typeof(EqualityComparer<TKey>));

        _keyedEntryCollection = new KeyedEntryCollection<TKey>(comparer);
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            AddEntry((TKey)entry.Key, (TValue)entry.Value);
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyCollectionChanged implementation

    private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, object item, int index)
    {
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, item, index));
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedAction action, object oldItem, object newItem,
        int index)
    {
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(action, newItem, oldItem, index));
    }

    private void OnCollectionReset()
    {
        OnCollectionChanged(new NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs(NotifyCollectionChangedAction.Reset));
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CollectionChanged?.Invoke(this, e);
    }

    #endregion

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation

    private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private void OnCommonPropertiesChanged()
    {
        OnPropertyChanged(IndexerName);
        OnPropertyChanged(ValuesName);
        OnPropertyChanged(KeysName);
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(_keyedEntryCollection.Count));
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not convinced by the index implementation. Since dictionaries don't have them, it should always be `-1` as not supported. In a context of dictionaries it's virtually meaningless as you cannot use it anyway.

See: [Interpreting NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/07/interpreting-notifycollectionchangedeve.html)

---

What I don't understand and find a little bit strange is that you sometimes use the internal dictionary and another time the keyed-collection for dictionary APIs:

> ```
> public Dictionary<TKey, TValue>.Enumerator GetEnumerator()
> {
>   return Dictionary.GetEnumerator();
> }
>
> public bool ContainsKey(TKey key)
> {
>   return _keyedEntryCollection.Contains(key);
> }
> ```

I see now why...

> ```
> _dictionary = _keyedEntryCollection.ToDictionary
> ```

You are copying the collection into a dictionary... not sure whether this is such a good idea either. This kind of breaks the dictionary contract because for some calls it won't be a `O(1)` operation anymore.

Comment: Hmm, since I wrote that in about 2 hours I guess I got tunnel visioned and didn't notice the obvious, very good point. Will there be significant benefits to changing it back to use a Dictionary internally?

Comment: @Denis I think so. It should then be easy to implement... you could create the `ObservableDictionary` as a decorator for a dictioanry, just add the `ObservableCollection` APIs on top of it and redirect all call the the other dictionary. This would be a pretty brainless task I suppose :]

Comment: Yes copying the dictionary is the reason why only use it when it's required. As I said in my question I was expecting to use the decorator pattern as that's usually the best way most of the time, but those indexes man.. They made me do so much unnecessary work.

Comment: @Denis water under the bridge... but I'm pretty sure you've learned a couple of new things so it probably wasn't entirely in vain :-) Well, let's wait for other reviewes and see what else they find :-]